# response xml is null although responsetext is valid .net webservice

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have a small webservice written in .NET as follows -

```
[WebMethod]  
public XmlDocument GetInfo(string key)  
{  
       //do stuff  
       string final = "<finalURL>" +"sample"+"</finalURL>";  
       XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();  
       doc.LoadXml(final);  
       return doc;    
}
```

The Webservice response in browser - 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBryl.png

And I am consuming this webservice in a simple Javascript like this -

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  
{  
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)  
  {  
   alert("REsponse Text = " + xmlhttp.responseText); //this is fine  
   //alert(xmlhttp.responseXML);  // does not even open the alert box, is null
  }  
};  
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:64400/WebService.asmx/GetInfo?key="+str,true);  
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");  
xmlhttp.send();
```

The responseText is fine but the responseXML is always null. I have sent the content type, and also checked that a valid xml is being returned by verifying that my browser is able to read the webservice response.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rg4J.png

Here is the xmlhttpRequest object itself, from IE9 (it has some non-unicode characters in responseBody)-

```
xmlhttp 
[object XMLHttpRequest] {
    ontimeout : null,
    responseBody : 㼼浸⁬敶獲潩㵮ㄢ〮•湥潣楤杮∽瑵ⵦ∸㸿਍昼湩污剕㹌慳灭敬⼼楦慮啬䱒>,
    timeout : 0,
    onload : null,
    onreadystatechange : function()    {    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)      {    alert("REsponse Text = " + xmlhttp.responseText);   parser = new DOMParser();   xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlhttp.responseText, "text/xml");      alert(xmlDoc);      path =,
    readyState : 4,
    responseText : "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  <finalURL>sample</finalURL>",
    responseXML : ,
    status : 200,
    statusText : "OK"
    ...
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Webservice modified to use UTF-16 -

```
string final = "<root>"+"<finalURL>" + "sample" + "</finalURL>" + "</root>";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(final);

XmlDeclaration xmldecl;
xmldecl = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-16", null);
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
doc.InsertBefore(xmldecl, root);
return doc;
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the encoding to `utf-16`?

Comment: @user1846192 - Thanks for your response. I will try to do that.

Comment: I modified my webservice to return with UTF-16 encoding but the responseText still has UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops.! Finally figured this out.
For some reason, just accessing the responseXML would cause error.
But on accessing the actual required element in the XML, there was no error and I was able to access that element.
Following will help better illustrate what I did.
I changed the XML on the webservice side a little, to include the string I am looking for as a value attribute -

```
[WebMethod]
public XmlDocument GetInfo(string key)
{
    //do stuff  
    string final = "<root>"+"<finalURL value=\"" + "sample" + "\"></finalURL>" + "</root>";
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(final);
    return doc;
}
```

And I accessed the value attribute of the XML in javascript as follows -

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
    alert("REsponse Text = " + xmlhttp.responseText 
        + "\n---------------\n"
        + "ResponseXML value = "+xmlhttp.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("finalURL")[0].getAttribute("value"));
    }
  };
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:64400/WebService.asmx/GetInfo?key="+str,true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
xmlhttp.send();
```

and it worked.! -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5ySS.png